# Multiple aggregations using JPA in a single query

Tags: jpa, join, jakarta-ee, count, jpql

I have a table to store items and need to select aggregated data based on multiple filters.

```
CREATE TABLE Parents(id int, name varchar)
CREATE TABLE Items(id int, parent_id int, field_A int,field_B int)
```

Now I want to count items where field_A=1, and also I want count items where field_A=1 and field_B=2 for all parents.

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, count1, count2 FROM Parents p
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT count(id) as count1, parent_id FROM Items WHERE field_A=1 GROUP BY 
parent_id) select1 ON select1.parent_id=p.id
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT count(id) as count2, parent_id FROM Items WHERE field_A=1 AND 
field_B=2 GROUP BY parent_id)
select2 ON select2.parent_id=p.id
```

What would be the right way to implement this using JPA as a part of JEE application?
In my understanding sub-queries are not supported in JPA and I have to use native queries.
Some test data:

```
insert into items(id,parent_id, field_A, field_B) values(1,1,1,1);
insert into items(id,parent_id, field_A, field_B) values(2,1,1,2);
insert into items(id,parent_id, field_A, field_B) values(3,1,2,1);
insert into items(id,parent_id, field_A, field_B) values(4,1,2,2);
insert into items(id,parent_id, field_A, field_B) values(5,2,1,2);
insert into items(id,parent_id, field_A, field_B) values(6,2,1,3);
insert into items(id,parent_id, field_A, field_B) values(7,1,1,3);
insert into items(id,parent_id, field_A, field_B) values(8,2,1,2);
insert into items(id,parent_id, field_A, field_B) values(9,2,1,2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh, joins with subqueries. Let me first simplify your SQL:

```
SELECT 
    p.id, 
    p.name,
    SUM(1) AS count1, 
    SUM(CASE i.field_B WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count2
FROM Items i
JOIN Parents p ON i.parent_id = p.id
WHERE i.field_A = 1
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
```

Your JPQL then becomes:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.name,
    SUM(1),
    SUM(CASE WHEN i.fieldB = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM Items i
JOIN i.parent p
WHERE i.fieldA = 1
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
```

> In my understanding sub-queries are not supported in JPA

They are, just not in `FROM` clauses (some JPA providers support that too, though).